# How to have Scrollview grow with its contant up to certain point and then stop and be able to actually scroll contant from this point

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I'm trying to make a popup coming out from below, which can increase height to a certain point (guideline in percentage, 10%). The content may be larger than this size, so it needs to be scrollable.

So my layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/clContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".1"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/gl_top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            >

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                />

        </ScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And what actually happens is this: ScrollView have zero height.
So my question is how to make popup with wrap_content layout height to scroll after it achieve its top point?

Comment: A ScrollView need an known Height and cannot set itselfs according to its content/children. The only way to achieve that is to manually compute children Heights on onMeasure/onLayout() overridden methods by extending ScrollView.